# Why isn't this block folding?

Tags: javascript, atom-editor

I just want it to fold like the if blocks above and below it... whyyyyyyy won't it?

Here is an abbreviated version... the middle block just won't seem to fold. I've opened and closed the file, made a new file with the same code in it, and it still isn't working

```
function gravity(reason, arg){
  console.log('applying gravity because ' + reason)
  const DEBUG = true;
  
  if (reason == 'swap' && (cursor.data('left')[1] > 0)){
    // Left side of cursor was at cursor.data('left')
    var empty = arg; //'left' or 'right'
    var was_empty = cursor.data(empty);
    var full = (arg=='left' ? 'right' : 'left')
    var was_full = cursor.data(full)
  }

  if(reason == 'match'){
    var stupid = 'dumb';
  } // end if
  
  // implementation could be more efficient using the arg, but eh

  if (reason=='command'){
    // Check beneath each grid spot which is above the first row and contains a block.
  }

  console.log('applied gravity')
  return findClusters();
  //return null;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please replace the image of code, with a text-based [mcve]. We cannot run and debug an image. --- Or is the issue with your text editor?

Comment: In addition to posting text, I don't see your `while` block terminated.

Comment: @Phix It is, the folding makes it show after the comment.

Comment: Please clarify whether you're asking about the code itself, or about the editor not folding it? If it's about the editor, this is not a programming question

Comment: It's about how the code and the editor are interacting...

Comment: @DJG that's not a programming question?